# parsing the structure and passing as a pointer argument

Tags: c++

I have a structure

```
struct PTC_ConfigurationH20
    {
        float period ;
        PTC_ConfigurationH20Probe probe[2] ;
        uint32_t padding ;

      }PTC_PACK;



 struct PTC_ConfigurationH20Probe
    {
        uint32_t probeSerialNumber;
        uint8_t probeType;
        uint8_t range;
        uint8_t mode;
        uint8_t padding1;
        PTC_H20PIDParameters pid;
        uint32_t padding;
    };
```

I read  the above PTC_ConfigurationH20 structure data as

```
H20::PTC_ConfigurationH20* tempConfiguration
                    = reinterpret_cast<H20::PTC_ConfigurationH20*>(message->GetData());
```

I need to pass the pointer for object  pid for probe[0], to the function

```
bool SetPIDConfiguration(uint8_t probenumber, const H20::PTC_H20PIDParameters& calib,
                             PTC_Return* ret);
```

Please Help

Comment: `SetPIDConfiguration(..., tempConfiguration->probe[0].pid, ...)`?

Comment: its just a pointer &ret, which significantly doesnt have a value here.

Comment: Have you tried `SetPIDConfiguration(0, tempConfiguration->probe[0].pid, NULL)` then? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried SetPIDCOnfiguration( 0,*(tempConfig->probe[0].pid), &ret)

Comment: I had tried &tempConfig->probe[0].pid, i have an error: no matching function for call to ****

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to pass the pointer for object pid for probe[0], to the function

Given:

```
H20::PTC_ConfigurationH20* tempConfig;
```

and given that SetPIDConfiguration takes as 2nd argument a const reference to H20::PTC_H20PIDParameters (assuming H20 is some namespace qualifier), one would be able to do the following:

```
SetPIDConfiguration( notRelevant, tempConfig->probe[0].pid, notRelevant );
```

Comment: The syntax of the function is SetPIDConfiguration(uint8_t probenumber, const H20::PTC_H20PIDParameters& calib,
                             PTC_Return* ret);

Comment: Yes. I specifically indicated that the 2nd argument is a reference and not a pointer. The function signature did not reflect the title of your post. (notRelevant) is not relevant to your question. tempConfig is a pointer, and is dereferenced by operator ->. probe[0] returns a reference to the zeroth element of the array probe (array of 2 elements to PTC_ConfigurationH20Probe), therefore the type PTC_ConfigurationH20Probe&. tempConfig->probe[0].pid provides your with the type required.

Comment: Error: Undefined reference to SetPIdConfiguration(****);

Comment: This means the function SetPidConfiguration has been declared but not defined. If SetPidConfiguration is declared in an h file, it has to be defined in some cpp file (it has to be implemented), and this file has to be compiled and linked with the rest of your program. In the event of it being part of a library, your program has to be linked with the library.

Comment: It has been defined and declared too in cpp file

Comment: ... and you've included the cpp file in your project. Post all the code, or at least post the applicable file.

Comment: Make sure the definition and declaration is the same... Post both of these.

Comment: Also, verify that they are in the same namespace, and that there arguments represent types in the same namespace.